# Cancelling databound control validating event doesn't suppress attempt to update data source

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, validation, data-binding

I'm not getting the behaviour I would expect for a TextBox bound to an integer property in a business object.

Here's what I did:

(1) Set the `DataSourceUpdateMode`, for the TextBox to: `OnValidation`.

(2) In the `Validating` event for the TextBox, set `e.Cancel = True` if Integer.TryParse fails.

(3) Add a handler to `Binding.Parse` and `Binding.BindingComplete` and place breakpoints in the handlers.

Run the application, put "asdasd" in the TextBox and tab out.
Despite setting `e.Cancel = True`, the `Parse` and `BindingComplete` events are both raised.
According to the documentation, setting `e.Cancel = True` should suppress any further logic.

I searched MSDN to find out why this happens but I can't find anything. Does any one know of where I can some details on this?

**ETA**: I added a handle to the Validated event as well. Here's the sequence of events:

Bad data:

(1) Validating. (I set `e.Cancel = True`)

(2) Parse

(3) BindingComplete

Good data:

(1) Validating

(2) Parse

(3) BindingComplete

(4) Validated

**ETA2**: A bit more info and a work-around.

The problem with this behaviour is if you have some validation that is not implemented in the property setter.

For instance, let's say my integer property has to be an odd number. I don't check for this in the property setter, so I do the check in the validating event.

As you can see, from the above behaviour, the value, as a legitimate integer, will be written to the data source, even if I cancel validation.

Despite the fact that the data source is updated, if you do set Cancel in the validating event, the Validated event will not be fired, so  you can still prevent the user from progressing.

**Work-Around::**

To stop the data source updating, you need to validate in the `Binding.Parse` event, and throw an exception - which prevents Binding from completing successfully.

Comment: good find. [Looks like a winforms bug][1].


  [1]: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=490267

Comment: Cheers, I've up voted the bug and added a work around.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a call to CancelEdit seems to make the difference.

```
    private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        bindingSource1.CancelEdit();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Comment: Note that CancelEdit will read the binding value into the control. This will erase the modification which could be a good thing (if you don't want to add a revert function on ESC keydown) or a bad thing because the user will have to retype the whole value as a correction.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I spent too much time looking for the same answer.  I hope that this helps someone else along the way.  CodeMag has a very good article on Object Binding that may help.

[Object Binding Tips and Tricks by CodeMag](http://www.codemag.com/article/0603011/Object-Binding-Tips-and-Tricks)

This is the form that I created to test the code that I wrote.

[image: Test Form with no Errors]

This image shows that the error provider is picking up and displaying the exception that is thrown because the value is outside the range that I set in the property setter.

[image: Test Form with Errors]

The key to being able to cancel the update is to put `e.Binding.BindingManagerBase.CancelCurrentEdit()` in the bindingsource complete event.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Class frmTest

Private WithEvents PersonBindingSource As New Person
Private WithEvents ErrorProvider1 As New ErrorProvider
Private WithEvents FirstNameBinding As Binding
Private WithEvents AgeBinding As Binding

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.ErrorProvider1.ContainerControl = Me
End Sub

Private Sub frmTest_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ErrorProvider1.DataSource = PersonBindingSource

    FirstNameBinding = TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", PersonBindingSource, "FirstName", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation)
    AgeBinding = TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", PersonBindingSource, "Age", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation)

End Sub

Private Sub FirstNameBinding_BindingComplete(sender As Object, e As BindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles FirstNameBinding.BindingComplete
    If Not e.BindingCompleteState = BindingCompleteState.Success Then
        e.Binding.BindingManagerBase.CancelCurrentEdit()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AgeBinding_BindingComplete(sender As Object, e As BindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles AgeBinding.BindingComplete
    If Not e.BindingCompleteState = BindingCompleteState.Success Then
        e.Binding.BindingManagerBase.CancelCurrentEdit()
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Public Class for Person

```
Public Class Person
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Protected Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional ByVal propertyname As String = Nothing)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname))
End Sub

Private _FirstName As String = "First Name"
Public Property FirstName() As String
    Get
        Return _FirstName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        If value.Length > 10 Then
            Throw New Exception("First name must be shorter than 10 characters")
        End If
        If (value <> _FirstName) Then
            _FirstName = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged()
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Private _Age As Decimal = 21
Public Property Age() As Decimal
    Get
        Return _Age
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        If value > 50 Then
            Throw New Exception("A person cannot be older than 50")
        ElseIf value < 21 Then
            Throw New Exception("A person cannot be younger than 21")
        ElseIf (value <> _Age) Then
            _Age = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged()
        End If
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

**EDIT:**

This was created using Visual Studio 2013 with .Net4.6